# Specified cast is not valid when run from debug folder in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, runtime-error, visual-studio-debugging

i have an application which gives me error saying `Specified cast is not valid`  when tried to run .exe from bin/Debug folder. I have no clue why it is happening since i run the app from `visual studio 2010`, it runs smooth. Any clues?

[image]

Comment: My guess is it's a bug of some kind. If you want more details from us, you'll have to supply more details to us. Some code, for example.

Comment: Do you have any stacktrace which contains information about where the error occurs?

Comment: I m using around 15 `usercontrols` which loads in a `panel` in a `form`. I dnt know which code to post as it give error in 5 such user controls but rest everything works fine. Well here is a image of the error i have http://s7.postimage.org/i3ysljhm3/error_Window.jpg

Comment: @MatthewWatson Sir please specify what kind of codes you require. m new to C# and visual studio

Comment: So, we can see from the stack trace that it's some issue with setting up auto-complete on a `TextBox` control - are you doing anything special with autocomplete? If not, try to identify which user control might be doing something with autocomplete...

Comment: @mortb Sir, if i put a try catch code then its not catching any exception. is der any other way i can do stacktrace? while debugging from visual studio i dont get any errors.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever thank you so much sir. The problem was with autocomplete textbox. there was a code written for textbox 'AutoCompleteCustomSource'. Its Resolved :) U saved my day :) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. As per the comment from Damien_The_Unbeliever, the problem was with setting up the `AutoCompleteCustomSource` for the textboxes. When i removed the Autocomplete code, the app started running smoothly.

Comment: So to fix it you just removed the code that was causing the problem?

Comment: i wanted the application to run. So i removed the code temporarily. I used the datagridview to load items on textchange as a replacement to autocomplete.